# Render mapbox vector tiles inside react-leaflet?

Tags: react-leaflet

Is there a way to use vector tiles from [react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet)?

I am aware of [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid), but it is not written for react-leaflet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `react-leaflet v2`, export the `MapBoxGLLayer` component wrapped with HOC `withLeaflet()` to get it working.

Steps:

1.Install `mapbox-gl-leaflet`.

```
npm i mapbox-gl-leaflet
```

2.Add mapbox-gl js and css to `index.html`

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

3.Add this component.

```
import L from "leaflet";
import {} from "mapbox-gl-leaflet";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { GridLayer, withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";

class MapBoxGLLayer extends GridLayer {
  createLeafletElement(props) {
    return L.mapboxGL(props);
  }
}

/*
* Props are the options supported by Mapbox Map object
* Find options here:https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#new-mapboxgl-map-options-
*/
MapBoxGLLayer.propTypes = {
  accessToken: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  style: PropTypes.string
};

MapBoxGLLayer.defaultProps = {
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
};

export default withLeaflet(MapBoxGLLayer);
```

4.Use the `MapBoxGLLayer` component.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    center: [51.505, -0.091],
    zoom: 13
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <MapBoxGLLayer
            accessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
            style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
          />
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Find the working code here (Add your own mapbox token): https://codesandbox.io/s/ooypokn26y

Comment: This was really helpful to me. The only thing is <MapboxLayer /> should, I believe, be <MapBoxGLLayer />

Comment: @MurliPrajapati I'm trying to wrap my head around the following:
import L from "leaflet";
import {} from "mapbox-gl-leaflet";
...
    return L.mapboxGL(props);

So 'L' is referencing leaflet, and it doesn't have a .mapboxGL() function - is this somehow pulling in from mapbox-gl-leaflet ? (trying to understand so i can convert to TypeScript)

Comment: @BruceM `L.mapboxGL()` function is provided by `mapbox-gl-leaflet`. This library adding that function to the global variable `L`. You can look that here:https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet/blob/b04674c701bada403ca428d08dce550b5ecd9863/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js#L236

Comment: Thanks so much - once I added the TypeScript types file it started working

Comment: Hey!
Any ideas how to add language detection support @mapbox/mapbox-gl-language ?
Just trying to find the way how to get access to map.AddControl

Answer (score 3):

There are some really nice vector tiles examples in this [react-leaflet issue](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/313) (mapbox-gl example reproduced below).

```
// @flow

import L from 'leaflet'
import {} from 'mapbox-gl-leaflet'
import {PropTypes} from 'react'
import { GridLayer } from 'react-leaflet'

export default class MapBoxGLLayer extends GridLayer {
  static propTypes = {
    opacity: PropTypes.number,
    accessToken: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    style: PropTypes.string,
    zIndex: PropTypes.number,
  }

  createLeafletElement(props: Object): Object {
    return L.mapboxGL(props)
  }
}
```

and the usage of the above component:

```
<Map>
  <MapBoxGLLayer
    url={url}
    accessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
    style='https://style.example.com/style.json'
  />
</Map>
```

**NOTE**: you may also need to `npm install mapbox-gl` and import that library and assign into to the global `window.mapboxgl = mapboxgl` to avoid issues with `mapboxgl` being undefined.

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot read property 'layerContainer' of undefined` when I try to access my extended GridLayer. so the message says : 

Cannot read property 'layerContainer' of undefined at MapBoxGLLayer.get (MapLayer.js:77). 

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [custom component](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/docs/Extending.md) by extending the MapLayer component.  You can see an example of how this is done in react-leaflet 1.0 in a project I contributed to [here](https://github.com/evansiroky/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer/blob/master/src/HeatmapLayer.js).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this question and is wondering how to do this with MapLibre GL JS (FOSS fork of Mapbox GL JS) as the backend renderer, you can do this but it's not immediately obvious. The MapLibre equivalent plugin is actively maintained now while the Mapbox one is not.

Here is the component code (in TypeScript) for a MapLibre tile layer that you can use instead of `TileLayer` in your React Leaflet `MapContainer`:

```js
import {
    type LayerProps,
    createElementObject,
    createTileLayerComponent,
    updateGridLayer,
    withPane,
} from '@react-leaflet/core'
import L from 'leaflet'
import '@maplibre/maplibre-gl-leaflet'

export interface MapLibreTileLayerProps extends L.LeafletMaplibreGLOptions, LayerProps {
    url: string,
    attribution: string,
}

export const MapLibreTileLayer = createTileLayerComponent<
    L.MaplibreGL,
    MapLibreTileLayerProps
>(
    function createTileLayer({ url, attribution, ...options }, context) {
        const layer = L.maplibreGL({style: url, attribution: attribution, noWrap: true}, withPane(options, context))
        return createElementObject(layer, context)
    },
    function updateTileLayer(layer, props, prevProps) {
        updateGridLayer(layer, props, prevProps)

        const { url, attribution } = props
        if (url != null && url !== prevProps.url) {
            layer.getMaplibreMap().setStyle(url)
        }

        if (attribution != null && attribution !== prevProps.attribution) {
            layer.options.attribution = attribution
        }
    },
)
```

Full sample code lives in this repo on GitHub: https://github.com/stadiamaps/react-leaflet-demo