# react-leaflet mapboxgl integration not working

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-leaflet

following the answer in this page : 
[Render mapbox vector tiles inside react-leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765309/render-mapbox-vector-tiles-inside-react-leaflet?answertab=active#tab-top)

When i export `MapBoxGLLayer` and import it to my main class,

like

```
import MapBoxGLLayer from './MapBoxGLLayer';
```

and try to access it in my render function, like:

```
<Map>
  <MapBoxGLLayer
    accessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
    style='https://style.example.com/style.json'
  />
</Map>
```

i'm getting this error which is pretty consistent.

```
MapLayer.js:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layerContainer' of undefined
at VectorgridLayer.get (MapLayer.js:77)
at VectorgridLayer.componentDidMount (MapLayer.js:38)
```

There is no leaflet to the props.

[image]

I don't know what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking hints from the answer you mentioned, I was able to get it working.
Your `MapBoxGLLayer.js`

```
import L from "leaflet";
import {} from "mapbox-gl-leaflet";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { GridLayer, withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";

class MapBoxGLLayer extends GridLayer {
  createLeafletElement(props){
    return L.mapboxGL(props);
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(MapBoxGLLayer);
```

The missing thing was the `withLeaflet` HOC.

**Usage:**

```
npm i mapbox-gl-leaflet
```

Add mapbox-gl-js and css to index.html

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />  

// Import the MapBoxGLLayer component mentioned above.
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    center: [51.505, -0.091],
    zoom: 13
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <MapBoxGLLayer
            accessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
            style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
          />
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can find the working example here:https://codesandbox.io/s/ooypokn26y
**Add your own mapbox token to see it working.**

Comment: that's correct the issue was `withLeaflet(MapBoxGLLayer)` that i was exporting wrong. but now I'm having another issue with my router, when it's trying to unmount itself i'm getting  
`Cannot read property '_leaflet_events' of undefined
    at removeOne (leaflet-src.js:2702)
    at Object.off (leaflet-src.js:2635)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in mapbox-gl-leaflet version 0.0.3 that is the "latest" in npm and was released two years ago.

```
onRemove: function (map) {
    if (this._map.options.zoomAnimation) {
        L.DomEvent.off(this._map._proxy, L.DomUtil.TRANSITION_END, this._transitionEnd, this);
    }

    map.getPanes().tilePane.removeChild(this._glContainer);
    this._glMap.remove();
    this._glMap = null;
}
```

The object this.map._proxy is not defined. Solution is to disable zoom animations with zoomAnimation={false} in the React Map Component. Then the branch is not taken in mapbox-gl-leaflet and you won't get this error.

This problem is solved in the master branch of mapbox-gl-leaflet in GitHub: 
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet/blob/954875e2e4269db313c99d522689bc08f4aadad2/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js

So try to update you libs.

Comment: yeap this was another issue with the library, so I ended up creating my own new functions and fixed the proxy not being defined.