# mapbox-gl-leaflet in react-leaflet with TypeScript?

Tags: react-leaflet, mapbox-gl-leaflet

I am trying to get this implementation described at [Render mapbox vector tiles inside react-leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765309/render-mapbox-vector-tiles-inside-react-leaflet) working, except I'm using TypeScript.

So my file looks like this:

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
import {} from "mapbox-gl-leaflet";
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { GridLayer, withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";

class MapBoxGLLayer extends GridLayer {
  createLeafletElement(props) {
    return L.mapboxGL(props);
  }
}

/*
* Props are the options supported by Mapbox Map object
* Find options here:https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#new-mapboxgl-map-options-
*/
MapBoxGLLayer.propTypes = {
  accessToken: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  style: PropTypes.string
};

MapBoxGLLayer.defaultProps = {
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
};

export default withLeaflet(MapBoxGLLayer);
```

However I get the following error:

> Property 'mapboxGL' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   import("c:/Users/.../node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'.ts(2339)

So leaflet doesn't have a definition for mapboxGL (which makes sense as mapboxGL is not a part of it) - but how do I create or reference a definition for mapboxGL that allows me to call L.mapboxGL(props) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve this error [type definitions for `mapbox-gl-leaflet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mapbox-gl-leaflet) needs to be installed, for example:

```
npm install --save @types/mapbox-gl-leaflet
```

And last but no least, [`react-leaflet` type definitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-leaflet) are **not** fully compatible with `react-leaflet v2` at the moment and some extra adjustment is required.
Since *the current version* of [`@types/react-leaflet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-leaflet) is targeting `react-leaflet v1`, some type definitions from version 2 are missing (refer [this thread](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/27887) for a more details), for example `withLeaflet` HOC. The good news is a **[PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/33367)** which adds support for version 2 has been already submitted (but not yet approved)

Anyway the missing `withLeaflet` type def could be declared like this:

```
declare module "react-leaflet" {
  const withLeaflet: <T>(component: T) => T;
}
```

and finally the component could be implemented like this:

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "mapbox-gl-leaflet";

declare module "react-leaflet" {
  const withLeaflet: <T>(component: T) => T;
}


import {Children, MapLayer, withLeaflet} from "react-leaflet";


export interface IMapboxGLProps extends L.MapboxGLOptions {
  children?: Children;
}


class MapBoxGLLayer extends MapLayer<IMapboxGLProps,{}> {

  public static defaultProps = {
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
  };

  public createLeafletElement(props:IMapboxGLProps)  {
    return L.mapboxGL(props);
  }

  public render() {
    return null
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(MapBoxGLLayer);
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9dpwcq)

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks so much!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks! 

I forgot to import "mapbox-gl-leaflet";