# Map component from react-leaflet library gives "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

just updated `react-leaflet` version from 1.9.1 to 2.0.0 and got a weird error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Map`.
```

I need to upgrade `react-leaflet` at least to version 2 so that I can use `withLeaflet` function to render vector tiles inside `react-leaflet`. Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317460/6399631

The file which contains `Map` component in my project;

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import {Map} from "react-leaflet";

class FdMap extends Component {
    mapRef = (map) => {
        if (map) {
            this.mapLeaflet = map.leafletElement;
            map.leafletElement.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

            map.leafletElement.on("focus", function () {
                map.leafletElement.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
            });

            map.leafletElement.on("blur", function () {
                map.leafletElement.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const {
          className,
          children
        } = this.props;
        const containerClassName = classNames(
          "fd-map",
          className
        );

        return (
            <Map ref={this.mapRef}
                 {...this.props}
                 className={containerClassName}>
                {children}
            </Map>
        );
    };
}

export default FdMap;
```

I'm using;

```
"react": "16.4.1",
"leaflet": "1.3.1"
```

Do you have any solution?

Comment: If you remove the children will it work?

Comment: Why are you passing all `props` in `Map`?

Comment: Tried removing children. It didn't work :( @EdwardChopuryan

Comment: I'm passing these props @JosephD. 
`{bounds: LatLngBounds {_southWest: LatLng, _northEast: LatLng}, boundsOptions: {padding: Array(2)}, children: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}], className: "listing-search-map", minZoom: 10, zoomControl: false}`
 These are actually Map related props.

Comment: @BurakGüneli try adding props one by one and see which prop caused the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue. The problem isn't related to `react-leaflet` or `props`. It appears that I'm using `react-dom` version `16.0.0`. Updated my `react-dom` version to `16.4.1` and my problem is solved now.