# Style-optimized vector tiles in react-leaflet v3?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox-gl, react-leaflet, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-leaflet

did recently anyone try to render [Style-optimized vector tiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/style-optimized-vector-tiles/) in react-leaflet **v3**?

I tried following the good examples found [here in an old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765309/render-mapbox-vector-tiles-inside-react-leaflet) , but they worked only in v2.

With v3 I get

```
Attempted import error: 'GridLayer' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'.
```

And GridLayer is no more there indeed. Any idea?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1):

I solved like that

I created this custom component "StyleLayer"

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import {} from "mapbox-gl-leaflet";

export default function StyleLayer({ styleUrl }) {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    L.mapboxGL({
      style: `${styleUrl}`,
    }).addTo(map);
  });

  return null;
}
```

And then I used it inside my "Map" component

```
<MapContainer center={coordinates} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={scroll}>
  <StyleLayer styleUrl="https://myStyleCloudEndpoint.com"></StyleLayer>
</MapContainer>
```

The main differences with the old examples linked above hence are:

- functional component instead of class (and "useEffect" hook)
- "useMap" hook by react-leaflet v3, which gives direct access to the map

Answer (score 0):

I made an NPM package for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-vector-tile-layer

It exposes a `<VectorTileLayer>` component which can also be embedded inside the react-leaflet `<LayersControl>`